# How can i call a servlet inside a javascript with attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want to call a servlet inside my javascript function.I want to pass a attribute to my servlet how can i do it.Can i have an example.

I find this that connect to my servlet but how i pass attributes.For example a nickname?

```
<script>
    function viewdeteils(var data) {
        document.location.href = "$  {pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/users/user";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where do you want to pass the attribute from?
Can you elaborate more

Comment: I have a jsp that contents the data.i want this data to pass to the servelt that calls /admin/users/user .Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: you can use ajax for that !! and the call of your servlet should be trigerred beyond an event